# How to set cookies on click event of button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

i have one dialogue box haveing one button.

```
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" onClick="savequote();" type="button" id="directory" value="Save quote" >
```

now i have set cookie by this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function savequote(){
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        document.cookie = emailid + "=" + email;
location.href = '03_drivers.php';
    }
    </script>
```

now i want to redirect this page on same page. i have tried this code in the function savequote()

```
location.href = '03_drivers.php';
```

but thats not working. So can you suggestme what i am doing wrong.

Comment: try to change button type to submit and then test

Comment: did you find out why it was not working ?

Answer (score 1):

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Prateek19/tGbnz/1/)**

You set `email` in wrong way.

```
document.cookie = emailid + "=" + email;
```

You should try this:

```
function savequote()
{
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  document.cookie="emailID="+email; "path=/";
  location.reload();  
}
```

and to reload same location use `location.reload();`

Comment: can you tell me how to get this cookie you have store in jsfiddle code actualy i had tried code function checkCookie()
{
var user=getCookie("email");
if (user!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + user);
  }
else 
  {
   alert("not set");
  }
} and this function get call on onload event of body but didnot get alert onload="checkCookie();"